# ¿Cómo dar formato a datos de una tabla bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Lo que me interesa es dar formato a los detalles que muestro de una tabla `boostrap`, como por ejemplo dar formato de pesos a las cantidades, les dejo un ejemplo de mi tabla:

[image: detalle]

y no sé como aplicar la función `formatMoney` que aplique en el TOTAL del encabezado, lo que quiero aplicarlo en el detalle les dejo mi código continuación.

```
<script>
function detailFormatter(index, row) {
    var html = [];
    $.each(row, function (key, value) {
                    if(key != 'idCompra' && key != 'StatusPart' && key != 'ClaveProv' && key != 'CveSuc'
                    && key != 'FaltaPed' && key != 'NumUser' && key != 'statusAut'
                    && key != 'FechHoraAut' && key != 'CveComp' && key != 'NoOrden'
                    && key != 'NomProv' )
        html.push('<td>' + key + ':<br>' + value + '</td>');
    });
    return html.join('');
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "dar formato de pesos a las cantidades?

Comment: al signo de pesos y la coma para separar los miles.

Comment: pero lo quiero aplicar en el detalle, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Igual es una pregunta básica pero, ¿el detalle es lo que muestras en la parte inferior de la imagen? ¿O el contenido de la tabla? Porque este último parece que se ve correctamente.

Comment: si lo que muestro abajo es el detalle que despliego y quiero dar formato de moneda al **importe** y **Total** pero del detalle.

Comment: Amigo tu fuiste el que ayudo haller gracias xD.

Comment: Sí, lo sé, y lo intentaré hoy también ^^. Sin embargo, ayer no vi el detalle de abajo aunque tampoco me hacía falta para lo que necesitabas.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu tiempo.

Comment: Como off-topic, te recomiendo vayas utilizando alguna librería si haces mucho éste tipo de operaciones, para generar contenido dinámicamente.

Comment: ya lo arregle amigo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, solo tienes que concatenar el símbolo que deseas sumar.

```
'$' + value
```

recuerda que tienes que agregarlo solo cuando ingreses el monto del total y si deseas cambiar el punto por la coma con un replace puedes hacerlo.

Comment: es que si le hago así me pone el símbolo a todos los valores porque **value** llama todos los datos

Comment: Si amigo como te comente arriba. tienes que colocar la validación.

Ejemplo: 

if(key == 'Total')
{
   '$' + value
}

Te lo coloco de esta manera para no decirte que re hagas el código. porque otra opción seria cambiar el método que estas usando para rellenar la tabla.